# Prevent stack overflow exception from occuring

Tags: c#, wpf

So whenever I change the window background from the code directly behind (preferences.xaml.cs) with

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Connect_4;component/resources/abstractPreferences.jpg")));
```

it works fine, however if I change it from a class using

```
Preferences preferences = new Preferences();
preferences.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Connect_4;component/resources/abstractPreferences.jpg")));
```

it result in a StackOverflow Exception at InitializeComponent();

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of Preferences like this?

Comment: @thewindev It already had a reference so I figured I could just use that one, how should I be doing it?

Comment: Look at the stack trace. The thing that happens over and over again is where the unbounded recursion is.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Preferences class? The constructor should be enough.
@EricLippert is right, look at the stack trace, it should show you which call is repeated.

Comment: Wait a moment, are you creating a new instance of Preferences in the constructor of Preferences?

Comment: @thewindev I'm changing it from a class called themer, preferences is the name of the form

Comment: Can you post the code of the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Preferences is a name of your control. And in the constructor of the Preferences you create new Preferences control. It is why you have StackOverflow exception.